# Injecting ElementRef to injecable error

Tags: angular

I have an issue with injecting `ElementRef` to my `Injectable`. Here is my code:

```
import {Injectable, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef, Inject} from "angular2/core";
import {Modal} from './Modal';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService{
    constructor(public _dcl:DynamicComponentLoader, public _el:ElementRef){

    }

    createModal(parent){
        this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(Modal,this._el, 'modal')
    }


}
```

My `Modal`:

import {Component} from "angular2/core";

```
@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    templateUrl: 'app/common/modal/Modal.html'
})

export class Modal{
    constructor(){

    }
}
```

This yields me to the following error:

> No provider for ElementRef! (HomeComponent -> ModalService -> ElementRef)

Why?

Comment: Where do you want to add the `Modal` in the DOM? The `ElementRef` needs to point to an existing component attached to the DOM.

Answer (score 10):

You can't inject `ElementRef` to a service class, only to a component or directive. `ElementRef` injects an instance where `.nativeElement` points to the DOM element the component or directive is attached to but there is no DOM element for a service.

In your example `ElementRef` can't be *any* `ElementRef`. The `ElementRef` determines where you `Modal` component is added to the DOM.

I suggest you add one single `Modal` component somewhere to the DOM that provides the service of showing content as a modal. This component injects a globally shared service and subscribes to events.

Other components that want to use the `Modal` component also inject the global service and emit a **component type** to be received by the subscribing `Modal` component which then uses `DynamicComponentLoader` to add the passed component to itself to be shown as modal.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

There are also several similar questions on SO already.

Comment: Hmm, thats interesting. Is it the same for renderer?

Comment: No, `Renderer` is not linked with a specific component instead for each method call on `Renderer` you need to pass `elementRef.nativeElement`.

Comment: There is an exception where you can inject `ElementRef ` in a service

Answer (score 6):

You can inject `ElementRef` in a service if this service is provided by a component.

The component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-rack-view',
    providers: [ MyService ],
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

The service:

```
@Injectable() 
export class MyService {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>) {} // OK 
}
```