# Dynamically loading component after bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am using the following:

```
this.DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(NewComponent, this.parent, 'new');
```

where `this.parent` is an `ElementRef` of my main class `App`.

However, this throws me an error of:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentView' of undefined.

I create `this.parent` like that:

```
setParent(parent){
    this.parent = parent.nativeElement;
}
```

and my `App` class:

```
export class App{
    constructor(_elementRef:ElementRef){
        Service.setParent(_elementRef);
    }
}
```

And my `NewComponent`:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'new',
    templateUrl: 'app/New.html'
})

export class NewComponent{
    constructor(){
        console.log("New Comopnent here")
    }
}
```

and `Service`:

```
export class Service{
    private parent:ElementRef;
    constructor(private DynamicComponentLoader:DynamicComponentLoader){

    }

    setParent(parent){
        this.parent = parent.nativeElement;
    }

    append(){
        this.DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(ModalComponent, this.parent, 'modal');
    }
}
```

Any ideas on where is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 contains a working Plunker example.

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you use `this.DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(NewComponent, t...` This doesn't work in the constructor for example.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I've updated my question. I use it in function

Comment: is it injectable service you have just mentioned?

Comment: And I should mentiont, that class `App` is main class, that is bootstraped.

Comment: @micronyks, its a provider

Comment: check this. Gunter just replied on that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495706/injecting-elementref-to-injecable-error

Comment: Where does `this.parent = parent.nativeElement;` come from? It doesn't look like you liked my suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495706/injecting-elementref-to-injecable-error/36495764#36495764 ? I advice against `DynamicComponentLoader` from a service. Use the service only for communication.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I've tried it, however I ran into issues of passing promise, to resolve on different type of user actions from modal. Indeed, I like idea of passing components in event emitter service, but I didn't managed to figure out how to pass promise back to the original comopnent

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem with passing the promise is. Usually you just pass it like any other value.

Answer (score 1):

`loadIntoLocation` expects at least these parameter/types:

```
loadIntoLocation(type: Type, hostLocation: ElementRef, anchorName: string)
```

You use the `nativeElement` of `parent`, this is not an `ElementRef` but an `HTMLElement`.

The solution is, when storing the parent, you should use:

```
 setParent(parent){
   this.parent = parent;
 }
```

I can only guess that this is where your problem comes from